# Gradual stop of rotation in code (WPF animation)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rotation

I need to have a gradual start and stop of animation (rotation) in code.

For start I have made next storyboard:

```
DoubleAnimation StartRotating = new DoubleAnimation();
StartRotating.From = 0;
StartRotating.To = 360;
StartRotating.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
control.storyboard.Children.Add(StartRotating);
Storyboard.SetTarget(StartRotating, control.FanCanvas);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(StartRotating, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
PowerEase easingFunction = new PowerEase();
easingFunction.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;
StartRotating.EasingFunction = easingFunction;

DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames persistentRotation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
persistentRotation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
persistentRotation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
Storyboard.SetTarget(persistentRotation, control.FanCanvas);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(persistentRotation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
persistentRotation.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(360, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))));
persistentRotation.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(720, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))));
control.storyboard.Children.Add(persistentRotation);
control.storyboard.Begin();
```

In one moment I need to stop it gradually. However, I have some problems:

1) I can't get a value of current `Angle`. I have tried this solution([How to get the rotation value of a UI Element in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579766/how-to-get-the-rotation-value-of-a-ui-element-in-wpf)), but value `rotation` is null... So, I can't get the `Angle`.

2) Then I want to gradualy stop animation, I change my storyboard, then stop it, then begin it again. So, there is a small pause in it. However, I'd like to have smooth animation without pauses.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To change the speed of an Animation smoothly, you have two main options. The first it to use one of the available [Easing Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751(v=vs.100).aspx), such as the [`ExponentialEase` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.exponentialease(v=vs.100).aspx) (example taken from this linked page):

```
<Rectangle Name="myRectangle" Width="200" Height="30" Fill="Blue">
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="30" To="200" Duration="00:00:3" 
                     Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="6" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>

</Rectangle>
```

The other, far simpler but not as configurable option is to use the [`Timeline.DecelerationRatio` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.decelerationratio(v=vs.110).aspx) on the used `Animation` object.

While I see that you are using the `EasingMode` property, I should like to add that it will be somewhat difficult to get smooth animation changes when using `KeyFrame`s.

---

UPDATE >>>

You should be able to find out the current value of the `RotateTransform` from the `RenderTransform` property like this:

```
double currentRotationValue = 0;
TransformGroup transformGroup = element.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
if (transformGroup != null)
{
    RotateTransform rotateTransform = transformGroup.Children[2] as RotateTransform;
    if (rotateTransform != null)
    {
        currentRotationValue = rotation.Angle;
    }
}
// Use currentRotationValue for whatever you want
```

This obviously assumes that your `RotationTransform` is in the third position of a `TransformGroup` element. If this is not the case, then you will need to adjust this code before running it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you see I have experience with Easing function and I have a solution for smoothy stoping with PowerEase Easyout. However, I need to know the current angle in the moment, when I want to start animation, which stops the rotation.